# Swift: check type of property from object (Reflection)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I want to use reflection to check the property type of a given object at runtime.

I use this code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit

class Object: NSObject
{
    var type:Int?
    var name="Apple"
    var delicious=true
}

let object = Object()

// now check the "type" property
println(reflect(object)[1].1.value) // this gives me nil
println(reflect(object)[1].1.valueType) // this gives Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>

// check for Optional... works fine - Says "Optional"
if reflect(object)[1].1.disposition == MirrorDisposition.Optional {
    println("Optional")
}

// check for type... does not work, because type is an optional - says: not Int
if reflect(object)[1].1.valueType is Int.Type {
    println("Int")
} else {
    println("no Int")
}
```

As you can see on this code, I can'n check "valueType", because it is an Optional.

But how can I check the type of this "Optional" property?

Thanks,
Urkman

Comment: You _know_ the type of the `type` property. It is an `Int?`. What else could you need to know?

Comment: Because, this will be generic, so "Object" is just an example. This could be any Object...

Comment: Right, but what I mean is, Swift doesn't really want you to do this. It doesn't have _real_ reflection, and this is deliberate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that optional Int is a different type from Int so you must check it with Int?.Type

```
if reflect(object)[1].1.valueType is Int?.Type {
    println("Int Optional")
}
```